# routing subfolder on S3 to wordpress blog on EC2 microsoft server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 to host static files for my website. Now I wanted to add Wordpress blog, which would be hosted in /blog subfolder. I followed an article which explains the easiest way to install Wordpress on EC2 on Microsoft Windows server here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/EC2Win_CreateWordPressBlog.html

I'm wondering how can I set /blog/* subfolder of my static site on S3 to rewrite all urls to a blog hosted on EC2.

How is that possible?

Thanks for help

Comment: Just an idea: Have you considered to use a Linux server for Wordpress? You might have other uses for not using one, but AFAIK there are way more tutorials for WP installation out on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know that's not possible. S3 supports redirects, but it won't act as a proxy for your dynamic content as there's no concept of URL "rewriting" (which can only really happen at the webserver level unless you're redirecting to a completely different domain). You have a few alternatives though.

1. Host your wordpress blog on a subdomain. blog.yourdomain.com keeps your blog and you just link to it from your static site.
2. Find a way to generate static files from your wordpress blog and put those files in the blog "subfolder". There are wp plugins that will do this I believe.
3. Just thought of a new one. Set up cloudfront in front of your website and use behaviors to forward requests to your blog server.

There is a final option where you make your default 404 page into a little js application that acts as a router for fetching pages from your wordpress backend but hahahahaha don't do that.